# WordPress - specific file for custom post type

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I know I can create custom files for specific custom-post-types

Unfortunately, the method works for me in one case:

- page-results.php for CPT = results
- but does not work for page-news.php where CPT = news
- or does not work for page-events.php where CPT = events

Why? can you have just a single file like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might clarify some things for you:

[Wordpress Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png)

The problem is, your Custom Post Types aren't actually "Pages". Even a "Page" isn't technically an actual Page, but a hierarchical Custom Post Type called "Page". Confusing? Yes. But there's a method to the madness.

The built-in Post Type known as "Pages" do function differently than the built-in Post Type called "Posts", which is why they have their own default templates and hierarchy. However, despite the fact that Wordpress allows you to extend their core to include your own Custom Post Types, at their root they're still considered "Posts" and will not follow the "Page" branch.

Your two options if you're following the standard Template naming conventions is to name your Custom Post Archive Templates "archive-results.php", "archive-news.php", and "archive-events.php".

As for your Custom Post Single Post Template, you would name them "single-results.php", "single-news.php", and "single-events.php".

If you want to fall back on an archive or single template for all three custom post types, simply don't define the separate post types and define an "archive.php" and "single.php" file.

Here's some more information on [Custom Post Type Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Type_Templates)